# RESTful API - validation of related records

Tags: validation, rest

I implementing RESTful API service and i have a question about saving related records.

For example i have `users` table and related `user_emails` table. User emails should be unique.

On client side i have a form with user data fields and a number of `user_email` fields (user can add any number of fields independently). When the user saves the form i must first make query to create record in `users` table to get her ID, ​​and only then i can make query to save user emails (because in now i have id of record which come with response after saving user data). But if user enters not unique email in any field then the request will fail. So I create a record in the `users` table but not create record in `user_emails` table.

What are the approaches to implement validation of all this data before saving?

Comment: it would be nice to explain to me for what downvote?

Answer (score 0):

This is nor related restful api but transactional processing on the backend. If you are using Java, with JPA you can persist both element in the same transaction then you can notice if there is a problem and rollback the entire transaction returning a response.

Answer (score -1):

I would condense it down to a single request, if you could. Just for performance's sake, if nothing else. Use the `user_email` as your key, and have the request return some sort of status result: if the `user_email` is unique, it'll respond with a success message. Otherwise, it'd indicate failure.

It's much better to implement that check solely on the server side and not both with the ID value unless you need to. It'll offer better performance to do that, and it'll let you change your implementation later more easily.

As for the actual code you use, since I'm not one hundred percent on what you're actually asking, you could use a `MERGE` if you're using SQL Server. That'd make it a bit easier to import the user's email and let the database worry about duplicates.

Comment: I think the union queries into a single query against the principles of REST. [Individual resources are identified in requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints).

Comment: @oledje Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, then. I was under the impression that the user's email *was* a unique identification of the user, even if not the supposedly-identity ID. Particularly since it sounds like you can convert an email directly to an ID. Although in any event, I still think there might be time to bend a rule or two in the interest of performance.

Comment: Also, whomever downvoted this, I'm curious of what in it is wrong, as defined by the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) page. "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I don't think anything I said is any of these things, but I'll delete or revise my answer if I'm mistaken.

Comment: One user can have a number of emails, but it doesn't matter because this is just example. I guess combine requests which affect (or create) different application entities it's wrong.

Comment: Okay, wait. I'll delete this answer in a moment if you feel it is dangerously incorrect. But how are you getting the user's ID in the first place? You said you're making a request, but what key are you basing said request off of?

Comment: I make `POST` request to create new user record which returns me new record ID (and other attributes). I think it's obvious.

Comment: Alright. Well, I still think a single request is more appropriate. Realistically speaking, you *are* talking about a single object: a user. Part of the purpose of an API (*part*) is that the object model doesn't have to relate directly to the database model. That's a big part of what these patterns are meant to enforce.

Comment: And wait, why did you ask a question about how do to this, then vote down and express major problems with the answer I gave? Were you looking for something in particular? I'd really love to help you find the right answer to your question, but it seems you're looking more for an argument than an answer.... I literally spend all day, every day working with REST APIs that I've written for clients. I'm not just making these things up. I'm speaking from my own experience and observations of major APIs in use in the *real world.* As in, not on some whitepaper.

Comment: Users and user_emails are completely different entities which stored in different tables, available by different urls, has own controllers and models.

Comment: Do you offer a solution that contradicts the principles of RESTful API. This does not help, and harm not only for me but also for those who will read your answer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just not understanding your question well enough. As I understand your setup, making a single call would not be in any way a violation of any REST protocol. But in any event, I still don't understand what you're asking. You seem to have a very strong idea of what you consider to be RESTful, so why are you posting a question about what the best practices of REST are? *What are you looking for here? What answer would help you?*